# base class extended object implamentation

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, polymorphism, base-class

Bit of a noobie question but hey ho.

Example:

```
BaseClass bc = new ExtendedClass(); //Assume ExtendedClass inherits from BaseClass
((BaseClass)bc).ExtendedMethod();
bc.ExtendedMethod();
((ExtendedClass)bc).ExtendedMethod(); //overridden in ExtendedClass

ExtendedClass ec = new ExtendedClass();
((BaseClass)ec).ExtendedMethod();
ec.ExtendedMethod();
((ExtendedClass)ec).ExtendedMethod(); //overridden in ExtendedClass
```

?

What implementations will `bc.ExtendedMethod();` and `ec.ExtendedMethod();` call at runtime? Will they be different? I assume the casted calls will call the specific implementation within the class.

edit: added relevant tag.

Comment: Why don't you give it a shot yourself, setup a sample project with base and child class and see

Comment: It's just with methods that only appear within the extension require a cast to be usable from the extended base class object and I was actually seeing if I could snag the actual concept of this *ty alex* and actually have this somewhere useful so that every programmer doesn't have to test this to find out.

Comment: Depends; is ExtendedMethod virtual?

Comment: It's a question about a concept - so it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Base
{
    public void Extends()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base class");
    }
}

public class Extend : Base
{
    public new void Extends()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Extend class");
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Base b = new Base();
        b.Extends();

        Extend e = new Extend();
        e.Extends();

        Base be = new Extend();
        be.Extends();

        Console.Read();

   }

}
```

Results in the following output:

```
Base class
Extend class
Base class
```

Note you can also use the `new` keyword in the `Extend` class to hide the base `Extends` function.

```
public new void Extends() 
{

}
```

Comment: Ahh ok - if you use virtual+override the last one is Extended; but if you use "new" the last is Base.

Answer (score 2):

In all three cases the overridden implementation of `ExtendedMethod` will be called, as you are creating an instance of `ExtendedClass`. After all, this is what [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) is all about.